# Jquery loop stop button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently setting up two buttons, start and stop for a jquery loop on html5. The start button works perfectly but whatever I try the 'stop' button remains inactive. I have seen many examples about stopping the loop but none seems to resolve the issue in the button being unresponsive. Sorry if this is such a simple question, but as a student I am quite frustrated and thus asking. cheers

```
"use strict";

var current_banner_num = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#banner-base").css("visibility","hidden"); 
    $("#banner-"+current_banner_num).show();

    var next_button = $("#start").button();
    var stop_button = $("#stop").button();

        next_button.click(function(){
            var timer = setInterval(myCode, 2000);
            function myCode() {

                //$("#banner-"+current_banner_num).hide();
                $("#banner-"+current_banner_num).fadeTo(800, 0);

                if (current_banner_num == 4) {
                    current_banner_num = 1;
                }
                else {
                    current_banner_num++;
                }
                $("#banner-"+current_banner_num).fadeTo(800, 1);
            }
        });
        stop_button.click(function(){
            function abortTimer(){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just defining a function again and again here. Just get rid of the function in the event handler:

```
stop_button.click(function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

This would execute the `clearInterval()`, while the code in your original question just defines a function, but doesn't call or do anything as you said. Hope it gets solved.

Comment: That was a super fast answer! thanks heaps for that! all solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable instead of a local one ,unwrap the clearInterval function

```
"use strict";

var current_banner_num = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#banner-base").css("visibility","hidden"); 
    $("#banner-"+current_banner_num).show();

    var next_button = $("#start").button();
    var stop_button = $("#stop").button();
     var timer = null;
        next_button.click(function(){
            timer = setInterval(myCode, 2000);
            function myCode() {

                //$("#banner-"+current_banner_num).hide();
                $("#banner-"+current_banner_num).fadeTo(800, 0);

                if (current_banner_num == 4) {
                    current_banner_num = 1;
                }
                else {
                    current_banner_num++;
                }
                $("#banner-"+current_banner_num).fadeTo(800, 1);
            }
        });
        stop_button.click(function(){
            clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
```

Comment: Another huge thanks to you for your input! What seemed annoyingly hard for ages solved in a couple minutes! Godsend :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 problems in your code. `timer` variable is not visible outside of `next_button.click(function(){ ... });` because it is local for this function, so you need to make it a little bit global; second problem is that in `stop_button.click(function(){ ... });` you just declare function `abortTimer` but do not call it (in general, it is not necessary to declare that function). I think your code should be like:

```
"use strict";

var current_banner_num = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#banner-base").css("visibility","hidden"); 
$("#banner-"+current_banner_num).show();

var next_button = $("#start").button();
var stop_button = $("#stop").button();
    var timer = null;
    next_button.click(function(){
        timer = setInterval(function(){
            //$("#banner-"+current_banner_num).hide();
            $("#banner-"+current_banner_num).fadeTo(800, 0);

            if (current_banner_num == 4) {
                current_banner_num = 1;
            }
            else {
                current_banner_num++;
            }
            $("#banner-"+current_banner_num).fadeTo(800, 1);
        }, 2000);
    });

    stop_button.click(function(){
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
```

Also it wasn't necessary to declare function `myCode` in nextButton function, so i clear it too for you